# Website livesearch doesn't work on mobile device browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this website where one while completing a phone number after the area code is filled with the first number an AJAX request is sent to the server where a search is conducted in a database and an html code for a table with a row for each entry representing each row from the results of the database is returned.

So if one were to type in the textbox #areacode#9 a request to the server would be sent for a search in the database for all people with a phone number starting with #areacode#9 and it would return the html code for a table with a row for each person.

That html overwrites what was in the div where the results are shown and one could click on an entry to autocomplete the rest. Pretty basic really and works fine in a browser on a laptop.

A friend of mine has an android and was testing it and for some reason nothing happens when he is writing the phone number. I tried it on my ipod and the same thing happens.

If while I am writing the number, lets say I wrote #areacode#93, nothing shows. But if I press Backspace then it works.

Any ideas?

Does it have something to do with how mobile devices treat the keyboard in the touch screen?

Comment: Ok, did some test using alert and event.keyCode..... It seems that on my iPod at least the numbers correspond to different ascii codes... And I was filtering ascii codes that weren't numbers to limit the probable invalid calls with characters other than numbers del and enter... Not sure what my thinking was at the time. It was some time ago but it seems like a good idea to not send a request to the server if the string is invalid and you know it. On the other hand we are talking about a very small task so maybe I can ignore it but I really don't like the idea

Comment: That's why backspace worked. It passed through the filtering and actually allowed the request to the server, then the search and of course the response with the HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am tired and sleepy and that's my excuse... Basically what happened is that keyCode deals with the actual keyboard keys and thus capital A and lower a are the same but number 1 and numpad 1 are different.49 and 97 respectively... Naturally the mobile devices keyboards don't have numpads so that's where my filtering went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a send issue I know that android and iphone's tend to input text in a manner which can represented in blocks.

So basically it send the text you type in burst. I can image that one of the conditions for send this is when you press the backspace key.